# Proving that two dimensional hyperbolic space is isometric to the sub-manifold of positive-definite matrices with unit determinant

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, hyperbolic-geometry, positive-definite, isometry

I'm studying the properties of the manifold of symmetric positive-definite (SPD) matrices and one of the papers that I'm reading mentions that for the case $n = 2$ we have an isometry between its subspace of matrices with unit determinant and $\mathbb{H}_2$, the 2-dimensional hyperbolic space (see [1, p.4-6] and details below).

**I'm trying to prove it but it seems to be pretty tedious, so I'm looking for resources, hints, or ideas on how to make it simpler**.

---

The distance between two SPD matrices is $$d_{\textrm{SPD}}(A, B) = \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^n \log^2 \lambda_i(A^{-1} B)},$$ where $\lambda_i(A^{-1} B)$ denotes the $i$th eigenvalue of the matrix $A^{-1} B$. The same distance is used when restricting to its subspace of SPD matrices with unit determinant, i.e., $\det(A) = \det(B) = 1$.

The isometric embedding that they propose uses the hyperboloid model of the hyperbolic space which in $\mathbb{R}^3$ consists of points with $x_0^2 - x_1^2 - x_2^2 = 1$ and $x_0 > 0$.  The distance function is given by $$d_{\mathbb{H}}(x, y) = \textrm{arccosh}\ b(x, y),\quad\textrm{with}\ \ b(x, y) = x_0 y_0 - x_1 y_1 - x_2 y_2.$$

Their suggested embedding maps a SPD matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} a&c\\c&b \end{bmatrix}$ with $a > 0$ and $\det(A) = a b - c^2 = 1$ to the point $x$ on the hyperboloid with $$x_0 = \frac{a + b}{2}, \quad x_1 = \frac{a - b}{2},\quad x_2 = c.$$

**The claim is** that $d_{\textrm{SPD}}(A, B) = d_\mathbb{H}(x, y)$ for all such matrices, using this mapping.

---

[1]: Chossat, P., & Faugeras, O. (2009). Hyperbolic planforms in relation to visual edges and textures perception. PLoS Computational Biology, 5(12), e1000625.

Comment: I'd check that the action of $PSL_2(\Bbb R)$ on the positive matrices of det 1 by $\phi_a(p) = apa^T$ is 1. transitive, 2. the stabiliser of $\Bbb 1$ is $PSO_2(\Bbb R)$, 3. is by isometries, 4. the induced representation $PSO_2(\Bbb R)$ on $T_\Bbb1(SPD_2)$ is irreducible. Points 1 and 2 imply that $SPD_2$ is diffeomorphic to $PSL_2(\Bbb R)/PSO_2(\Bbb R)$, which is the same as $\Bbb H_2$. Now the Riemannian metric on $SPD_2$ resp. $\Bbb H_2$ is uniquely determined by its value on a point (since the group of isometries $PSL_2(\Bbb R)$ acts transitively on these spaces (point 3)). ...

Comment: ... Point 4 tells you that up to scale there is only one scalar product on $T_{\Bbb 1}(SPD_2)$ that is invariant under the representation of $PSO_2(\Bbb R)\cong SO_2(\Bbb R)$. This means that the metrics on $SPD_2$ and $\Bbb H^2$ must be equal (up to rescaling by global constant).

Comment: @s.harp Thanks for the proof sketch!  You can add it as an answer, it's very helpful.

Comment: @s.harp Also, your proof shows that the two spaces are isometric, but how would you go about showing that the *particular* embedding map that I included in my question *is* an isometric embedding?  

I tried to check it experimentally and I indeed notice that the two distances are equal *up to* a scaling of $\sqrt{2}$.  This is probably the "global constant" in your comment, but how can I make this rigorous?